# Alert silencing on Google Managed Prometheus is only temporary

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, google-managed-prometheus

I use Google Managed Prometheus on my v1.25.16-gke.1268000 cluster, and I noticed that everytime I go and silence an alert, regardless of how long I set the silence for, the silence simply disappears after the AlertManager gets restarted. Why is this? I never experienced this with a self managed version of Prometheus.

I tried setting up different expiration times for the silences, but eventually it just disappears regardless of the expiration time.